# Weird syntax in a module definition (.def) file - "?" and "@"

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some legacy code for a program, the "exports.def" file in particular, and there are some things i don't quite get about the syntax used in there.

```
    ??0Hold@c4_ThreadLock@@QEAA@XZ
    ??0c4_Allocator@@QEAA@XZ
    ??0c4_BaseArray@@QEAA@XZ
    ??0c4_BlockedViewer@@QEAA@AEAVc4_Sequence@@@Z
    ??0c4_Bytes@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z
    ??0c4_Bytes@@QEAA@PEBXH@Z
    ??0c4_Bytes@@QEAA@PEBXH_N@Z
    ??_R0?AVc4_FormatV@@@8   DATA
    ??_R0?AVc4_FormatX@@@8   DATA
    ??_R0?AVc4_GroupByViewer@@@8     DATA
    ??_R0?AVc4_Handler@@@8   DATA
```

The exported variables start after one or more question marks and sometimes "0"s, which the docs don't say anything about, and I have no clue what they stand for. The "@"s here also make no sense to me. Could someone explain this?

Comment: Looks like [name mangled](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) names to me.

Comment: The non mobile version of the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) @JesperJuhl posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is [a module-definition file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=vs-2019).

> Module-definition (.def) files provide the linker with information about exports, attributes, and other information about the program to be linked.

In it you see is a list of exported names, which are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++). Some characters are added to the name to achieve uniqueness of names and to store additional information.

Specifically for Microsoft's Visual C++ series of compilers:

> All mangled C++ names start with ? (question mark). Because all mangled C names start with alphanumeric characters, @ (at-sign) and _ (underscore), C++ names can be distinguished from C names.
> The structure of mangled names looks like this:
>
> Prefix ?
>
> Optional: Prefix @?
>
> Qualified name
>
> Type information

See this [link](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling) for additional details.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems to be what i'm looking for.